# Start loading while animating a page transition

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xaml, microsoft-metro, loading

One of the basic design principles of the Metro design language (I'm sorry, Windows 8 style UI) is the principle of motion. One of the reasons for this is that loading can occur while the animation is being run. Great idea.

Now, how are you supposed to load anything (say, from a REST server or from isolated storage) while this animation is running? I guess this won't be possible before the page in question starts its "in"-transition, but how do I start loading already at the beginning of this animation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what i checked(Contructor, Page_Loaded, OnNavigatedTo) constructor is beeing called first and Page_Loaded last. 
starting async load task in constructor might work.

Other idea that comes to my head is starting AsyncTask before invokin Naviagte to the page.
If you want to do it on starting page of application I would try starting loading in App constructor.

Comment: Yep, depending on speed of the connection, this could work quite well, I use a similar thing to reload data from a local DB before/during the page transition, which "hides" the flicker that would occur with a standard rebinding.

Comment: I used the first one - starting the data load in the constructor, however you can also do it on the OnNavigatedTo event, which is fired before the transition starts as far as I can tell.